# Hibernate IS-A relation mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have an entity model(a) and some other entities(x) like mobile, tablet, car etc.

The entities(x) have a primary key that references to the primary of the model(a), so the entities(x) can take only the values of the model(a) entity.
I'm talking about an IS-A relationship.

I also need to have access from both ends.

I need help with the mapping in hibernate.
What i do right now and does not work:

- model entity

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Model")
@Table(name = "model", schema = "mysch")
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "model_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 255, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "model")
    private Mobile mobile;
```

- mobile entity

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Mobile")
@Table(name = "mobile", schema = "mysch")
public class Mobile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mobile_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mobile_id", referencedColumnName = "model_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_Mobile_Model"))
    private Model model;
```

What i want is to create a PK in mobile table that references to the PK of the model table.

Comment: The relation seems wrong. From what I understand, every `Mobile` has-a `Model`, but one `Model` can be referenced by multiple `Mobile`s. Is that right? If so, you should use a `@ManyToOne` relation in `Mobile` and possibly a `@OneToMany` relation on `Model`.

Comment: No, sorry if my explanation was not good enough. Mobile is a pk, so it has to be unique. So, let's say that model has the ids: 1,2,3,4,5 .
id = 1 may be used in mobile.
id = 2 may be be used in mobile too.
id =3 can be used in car.
but id =1 cannot be used in mobile a second time.
Both ids are PK, so they are unique..

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution.
Seems to work for now. I will make jpa queries later to test it. Though the schema in the DB, seems to be exactly what i wanted.
Here is what i did:

- model entity

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Model")
@Table(name = "model", schema = "sch")
public class Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "model_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 255, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "model")
    private Mobile mobile;

}
```

- mobile

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Mobile")
@Table(name = "mobile", schema = "sch")
public class Mobile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mobile_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Model model;

}
```

I don't like the generated PK column name of the mobile though... It goes like:
"model_model_id".

Though it seemed to be working well... I fell into a problem. I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.lang.String.equals(String.java:1009)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Model.equals(Model.java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Mobile .equals(Mobile .java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Model.equals(Model.java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Mobile .equals(Mobile .java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Model.equals(Model.java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Mobile .equals(Mobile .java:6)
at com.dc.sch.entity.Model.equals(Model.java:6)
```